# Improving crit chance for a non-evil fighter

Tags: dnd-3.5e, optimization, fighter, critical-hit

I'm looking to build a fighter that fights with a scythe and want to maximize his crit and damage, with more crit then damage if they conflict at any point.

I read that the best thing out there for a crit focused character is the 'disciple of dispater' prestige classes, but our DM does not allow any evil characters, so I cannot use this.

I looking to get to at-least 15-20 crit chance. The most I was able to get to was 17-20 with the Improved Critical and Masters Critical (From the Weapon Master Prestige Class).

Any help with getting the 15-20 threat range would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I know that weapons with 18-20 crit range are better for crit builds, but my character is a [mortalized](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mortalize) reaper so he must use the scythe.

Comment: Which Weapon Master prestige class are you referring to? I'm pretty sure it's not the Weapon Master from Sword and Fist, or the Exotic Weapon Master from Complete Warrior. Is it [this homebrew Weapon Master](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Weapon_Master_%283.5e_Prestige_Class%29)? That's the only one I can find with an ability called Master's Critical.

Comment: ...before someone wastes their time trying to track down an alternative to the disciple of Dispater, have you double-checked with your DM who won’t allow Evil characters that he *will* allow abusing 3.0 material that was never updated to prevent critical-threat-range stacking, as all 3.5 material does? Because most DMs see that change as a thing 3.5 did, and don’t allow grandfathered 3.0 material to get around it.

Comment: Before ignoring disciple of Dispater completely, note that there're no rules for an *ex*-disciple of Dispater, so if you're playing a constructed character that's built at a certain level (rather than an organic character that must advance through levels), it's apparently legit to take the first level, switch alignments, and keep advancing in disciple of Dispater. However, some DMs see this as shady. (But, hey, others see it as a story of redemption.)

Answer (score 3):

I know three ways to boost crit range beyond the "double crit range, doesn't stack" things. However, you can't do them with a fighter.

## Streetfighter barbarian: +1 crit range

The [streetfighter](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112031718/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/we/20070228a) barbarian gains +1 to his crit range when attacking flat-footed opponents or charging. You need 7 levels of barbarian to gain this ability.

## Arcane duelist: double crit range

At level 7, the [arcane duelist](https://web.archive.org/web/20210722212013/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/re/20030224a) gains False Keenness, and 1/day/level can make his weapon *keen*. This explicitly stacks with Improved Critical and *keen* weapon property, but not spells. **It's 3.0 material**, but if your DM allows Disciple of Dispater, he should allow this too.

Unfortunately, it's difficult to enter - you need +6 base attack bonus and the ability to cast 1st level spells. You will want to enter with something like duskblade or hexblade, who gets arcane spellcasting and full base attack bonus, and even then, you won't have this ability before level 13.

## Psychic weapon master: +2 crit range

At level 7, the [3.5-updated psychic weapon master](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111173022/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/psm/20040827d) gains Improved Critical, but if he already had Improved Critical, he gains +2 to his crit range. This increase only applies to the crystal weapon that the psychic weapon master has bonded with, so you'll need to have a crystal scythe.

Psychic weapon master is also difficult to enter - you need 3rd level psionic powers, base attack bonus +5, and a bunch of feats. The fastest way to enter is as a 7th level psychic warrior, meaning you need to be level 14 to gain this ability.

Comment: I would note that a Streetfigher Barbarian 7/Sorc 1/Arcane Duelist 7 (ECL 15) is feasible and would accumulate on top of the Keen property of the Scythe, however I am not quite clear on how to sum up the parts (all those +1 and double/triple). Also, from the article you linked, the streetfighter barbarian also gains the +1 to threat range when charging.